# Ftp sync with special character in password

Tags: ftp, applescript, special-characters

i write a script who sync folder from ftp server and local folder. It works perfectly thanks to rsync.
I write this script with AppleScript.

But ftp password has changed and now there is an @ on it.
With this new password i can not log because of the @.

There is what i try:

- replace it with %40 but it doesnt work neither.
- log using cmd+k in the finder but it doesnt works with this password.

There is part of script:

tell application "Finder"

```
try
    mount volume "ftp://user:pass@word@ftp.domain.com"
end try
end tell
```

How do i have to write the password ?

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of thoughts about your post. 1. Finder does not know the `mount volume` _command_, so don't use it directly in a `tell "Finder"` _statement_ block, it's built into AppleScript. 2. The AppleScript `mount volume` _command_ does't use the `"ftp://user:pass@word@ftp.domain.com"` _syntax_, but the _command line_ version of `ftp` supports that _syntax_. Read the AppleScript documentation for the `mount volume` _command_ and the manual page for the _command line_ version of `ftp` if you want to run the _command_ through, e.g., a `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: ok but how can i mount this volume in order to do rsync?

Comment: In your comment you said, "ok but how can i mount this volume in order to do rsync?", well from what I said in my first comment, I'd have thought you'd see the answer to that is to **use a proper syntactically formed command with valid values**! Did you even bother to read the documentation as mentioned in my first comment? See the AppleScript Language Guide [**mount volume**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW17) _command_ for is proper _syntax_ and examples.

Comment: Or if you want to use the _command line_ version of the `ftp` _command_, then in Terminal `man ftp` and read it. Then if you want to run it in a `do shell script` _command_ see the AppleScript Language Guide [**do shell script**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) _command_ for its proper _syntax_ and examples.

Comment: use a proper syntactically formed command with valid values! is what i'm looking for...mount volume with other ftp works. This one doesnt work because there is an "@" in the password. I know i can connect to the server with do shell script by replacing @ with %40 but it doesnt mount the volume in the finder and i need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a linux bash script with a password with a $ sign in it, and found I could solve it by putting the strings between ' ', like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='ftp.domainname.com'
USER='username'
PASSWORD='pa$$word'

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
mget *.mp3
close
bye
EOF
```